# Unable to set scheduling policy using sched_setscheduler() function?

Tags: process, operating-system, scheduling, job-scheduling

I am new to OS programming. So, I wrote this code to change the scheduling policy of a background process, whose process ID I supply through a command line argument, but the sched_setscheduler() function fails, giving an error, "Function not implemented"

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct sched_param param;
    param.sched_priority = 80;
    int pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    int policy = sched_getscheduler(pid);
    printf("Current policy: %d\n", policy);
    if(sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_FIFO, &param) == -1){
        perror("Scheduler policy cannot be set");
    }
    int new_policy = sched_getscheduler(pid);
    printf("New policy: %d\n", new_policy);
}
```

Can someone please tell me why this happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I wrote this code to change the scheduling policy of a background process, whose process ID I supply through a command line argument

Here is the problem. [`sched_setscheduler(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) gets a **thread id** not a **process id**. For single thread processes `PID` and `TID` coincide, but in multi-threaded processes every thread has its own `TID`.

The fact that the argument is named `pid` and is of type `pid_t` might be misleading and even some old man-pages of `sched_setscheduler(2)` wrongly talk about processes, but this function is actually about threads.